# How to exclude a matched pattern in file and lines above and below it?

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to print lines containing `Result: False` and three lines above it, except when one of the three lines contains `service.dead`.

So for the following file:

```
      ID: service1
Function: module.run
    Name: ps.kill_pid
  Result: True
 Comment: State was not run because onfail req did not change
 Started: 16:37:23.237741
Duration: 0.0 ms

      ID: service2
Function: service.dead
    Name: SomeService
  Result: False
 Comment: check_cmd determined the state failed
 Started: 16:37:23.567741
Duration: 8286.0 ms

      ID: service3
Function: service.running
    Name: SomeService
  Result: True
 Comment: Started Service SomeService
          Delayed return for 5 seconds
 Started: 16:38:22.956741
Duration: 47438.0 ms

      ID: check_status
Function: cmd.run
    Name: http.query http://1.1.1.1 
  Result: False
 Comment: Attempt 1: Returned a result of "False"
          Attempt 2: Returned a result of "False"
          Command "http.query http://1.1.1.1"
 Started: 16:40:57.424741
Duration: 50180.0 ms
```

I want to print only

```
ID: check_status
Function: cmd.run
    Name: http.query http://1.1.1.1 
  Result: False
```

I managed to print three lines above `Result: False` and remove two lines below `service.dead` with the following command:

```
grep -B 3 'Result: False' /my/file | sed '/service.dead/,+2d'
```

But I can't find how to remove the line above `service.dead`. My current output is:

```
      ID: Service2
---
      ID: check_status
Function: cmd.run
    Name: http.query http://1.1.1.1 
  Result: False
```

Any elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        RS = ""
        FS = OFS = "\n"
    }
    $4 ~ /Result: False/ && !($2 ~ /service\.dead/) {
        print $1, $2, $3, $4
    }
' infile
```

This does the following:

- sets the record separator `RS` to the empty string, which tells awk that records are separated by blank lines
- fields are separated by newlines both for input (`FS`) and output (`OFS`)
- for each record, we compare fields 4 and 2 to the desired values and print the first four fields if the match worked

Comment: I copied & paste your code but it doesn't work for me. Obviously I changed "infile" to my file, but nothing printed.
I managed to get the desired result by running 'grep -B 3' on the output after sed, which is good enough, but I would still like to know how to delete line above matched pattern.
Thanks!

Comment: @Maayana If I copy your input file and run my command on it, I get exactly your desired output. Is there anything other than a blank after the colon? A tab, perhaps? What if you replace `/Result: False/` with `/Result:[[:blank:]]*False?`

Comment: sorry for late response. For this specific example file your code works just fine.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes I'm sure there is only blank after the colon.
And you are correct, for this specific example file your code works just fine.
But in my original file there are additional blocks (with the same structure of id: function: name: etc) and some text that I removed for security reasons but I left it as similar to the original as possible. According to your explanation it should work, but I'm not familiar enough with awk to debug it.
Tried your suggestion with [[:blank::]] but still doesn't work on original file.

Comment: @Maayana I can't know or write an answer for what I can't see, I'm afraid. If you want to write a new question about this, make sure to create a [mcve] that includes more cases and describe the structure of what you're trying to extract.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;/service\.dead/ID;/Result:\s*False[^\n]*$/Ip;D' file
```

Use the `-n` option to turn off automatic printing. Open a four line window throughout the length of the file. If any of the four lines held in the pattern space contain the text `service.dead` delete the first and append another. If the last of the four lines in the pattern space end in `Result: False` print the pattern space. Regardless of the previous outcome, delete the first and append the next, keeping the four line window.

Comment: This works for the example file I posted, but not for my original file...
My original file consists mostly of these blocks and some additional info that I removed.
Each line in these blocks has some tabs before it, and after each block there is actually some "-----" that I was unable to put in this example cause when I pasted it the whole text was messed up so I removed it.

Comment: @Maayana without access to your original data it is hard to say why this solution does to solve your problem.

Comment: my file contains these blocks, some extra lines below and above these blocks and some extra tabs before each line. According to your explanation it should work... I managed to solve this with additional grep -B 3 after deleting service.dead. I appreciate your effort either way.

Comment: @Maayana the above solution is generic for any n-lines problem, however the trigger that prints the solution was dependent on the data you presented. I have generalised the trigger as far as possible by replacing specific space by  white space and ignoring any characters following the match to the end of the window. This may afford you a robust solution. P.S. I also made matches non-dependent on case.

Comment: Great! now it's working as expected!! Much appreciated. thank you!